# Issues harmonizing my dual boot

Tags: mount, filesystem, dual-boot, storage

I tried to follow this guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/
I'd wish and can't figure out how to make it work.
I've been dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 on my laptop for years, but i just wiped my hard drive in an attempt to follow this guide, and use one large shared storage system for the two OS's.  I partitioned my 320gb HD into a 15 gig NTFS, 15 gig EXT4, 4 gig swap, and the rest as a NTFS storage partition.  I installed ubuntu 11.10 from a disc and followed all the steps in the guide including configuring my subfolders.  I then went straight to installing windows 7, but my install disc was pre release and would not accept my product key.  When i tried to restart and go into linux, the computer didn't even recognize the ext4 file system and went straight to the faulty windows system, I messed around with the root terminal and I think it had issues mounting the filesystem.  I had to use a bootable partition tool to wipe the hard drive again and start over. I just finished doing a fresh install of linux, currently ubuntu 11.10 is all i have on my computer. I think these instructions might be outdated, but i'm not as computer literate as i want to be and can't seem to figure out how to make it work

I did a search, and there were plenty of topics on dual booting but I couldn't find anything exactly tailored to this. Hope it isn't a repost

Comment: Please respond to Sergey's answer as it is sound advice. Also there does exist an ext4 Windows driver which might help in simplifying your dual boot dilemma. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to install Windows first, and then install Ubuntu.

Windows has never been particularly cooperative in terms of sharing a computer with other operating systems - its install procedure simply wipes whatever boot loader is currently installed and installs its own. Did you really expect Windows to add Ubuntu to its boot menu? :)

Ubuntu, on the other hand, will automatically recognize and add a Windows partition to GRUB menu.

After you have the two OSes dual-booting, you can proceed to setting up the shared folders etc. as per the tutorial you've linked to.